# Python installation issues

Tags: python, pip

I am trying to install python latest version in my Ubuntu 18.04, but I am getting the following error:

```
python setup.py install 

File "setup.py", line 354 + f'found:\n{tzpaths!r}\nwith invalid paths:\n' ^
```

I tried:

```
pip install Python-3.10.5 

[sudo] password for rb: 
The directory '/home/rb/.cache/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag. The directory '/home/rb/.cache/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag. Collecting Python-3.10.5 Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement Python-3.10.5 (from versions: ) No matching distribution found for Python-3.10.5
```

I tried without sudo:

```
pip install Python-3.10.5 Collecting Python-3.10.5 Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement Python-3.10.5 (from versions: ) No matching distribution found for Python-3.10.5
```

Could you please provide some solution?

Comment: `pip` is for installing packages into an existing Python installation, not for installing or updating Python itself.

Comment: Try conda instead of pip

Answer (score 1):

try using apt
`sudo apt install python3`